# R: Loop through data.frame in row-pairs

Tags: r, performance, loops, parallel-processing, pairwise

I would like to process some GPS-Data rows, pairwise.

For now, I am doing it in a normal for-loop but I'm sure there is a better and faster way.

```
n = 100
testdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(runif(n,1,10), runif(n,0,360), runif(n,14,16), runif(n, 46,49)))
colnames(testdata) <- c("speed", "heading", "long", "lat")
head(testdata)

diffmatrix <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = dim(testdata)[1] - 1))
colnames(diffmatrix) <- c("distance","heading_diff","speed_diff")

for (i in 1:(dim(testdata)[1] - 1)) {
  diffmatrix[i,1] <- spDists(as.matrix(testdata[i:(i+1),c('long','lat')]),
                             longlat = T, segments = T)*1000
  diffmatrix[i,2] <- testdata[i+1,]$heading - testdata[i,]$heading
  diffmatrix[i,3] <- testdata[i+1,]$speed - testdata[i,]$speed
}
head(diffmatrix)
```

How would i do that with an apply-function?

Or is it even possible to do that calclulation in parallel?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the end condition but with `dplyr` you can do all of this without using a for loop.

```
library(dplyr)
testdata %>% mutate(heading_diff = c(diff(heading),0),
                    speed_diff = c(diff(speed),0), 
                    longdiff =  c(diff(long),0), 
                    latdiff = c(diff(lat),0)) 
         %>% rowwise() 
         %>% mutate(spdist = spDists(cbind(c(long,long + longdiff),c(lat,lat +latdiff)),longlat = T, segments = T)*1000 ) 
         %>% select(heading_diff,speed_diff,distance = spdist)

#   heading_diff speed_diff distance
#          <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1         15.9      0.107   326496
# 2       -345       -4.64     55184
# 3        124       -1.16     25256
# 4         85.6      5.24    221885
# 5         53.1     -2.23     17599
# 6       -184        2.33    225746
```

I will explain each part below:

The pipe operator `%>%` is essentially a chain that sends the results from one operation into the next.  So we start with your test data and send it to the mutate function.

Use `mutate` to create 4 new columns that are the difference measurements from one row to the next.  Adding in 0 at the last row because there is no measurement following the last datapoint. (Could do something like NA instead)

Next once you have the differences you want to use `rowwise` so you can apply the `spDists` function to each row.

Last we create another column with `mutate` that calls the original 4 columns that we created earlier.

To get only the 3 columns that you were concerned with I used a `select` statement at the end.  You can leave this out if you want the entire dataframe.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your method is more than 10x faster than the normal for-loop!